# Hoverzoom alternative for Firefox

Tags: firefox-extensions

I used to use [Hoverzoom](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hover-zoom/nonjdcjchghhkdoolnlbekcfllmednbl) on Chrome. I moved to Firefox recently and I'm looking for a similar alternative. Is there a Firefox version / port of Hoverzoom? If not, is there a similar extension?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Thumbnail Zoom Plus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/thumbnail-zoom-plus/) is what I use. It also provides the ability to easily save the expanded image.

AFAIK there is no direct port.